# Spacy.io multithreading with custom pipelines

Tags: python, multithreading, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to use Spacy.io with custom pipelines for language processing, but it seems that when I add a custom function to the pipeline the process runs only on one thread. With default pipeline process uses all the threads specified.

This is how I defined pipeline:

```
nlp = spacy.load(language, create_pipeline=custom_pipeline)
```

This is `custom_pipeline` function:

```
def custom_pipeline(nlp):
    return (nlp.tagger, score_vocab_pipe)
```

This is how I run the pipeline:

```
nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=1000, n_threads=8)
```

Are there any requisites for custom pipeline functions to support multithreading with spacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://explosion.ai/blog/multithreading-with-cython) might give you a better understanding of how the multi-threading is implemented. The multi-threading is described in the docs [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/processing-text#multithreading).

In short: the tagger doesn't currently release the GIL, so the tagger.pipe() method is just a generator that applies the tagger one-by-one. The tagger should be quite fast for most workloads with one thread per process, especially since it doesn't use much memory. You can see the recipe for multi-processing batch jobs [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/parallel_parse.py).

We could release the GIL around the tagger as well, to allow efficient multi-threading. If you'd like to work on this, we can talk about it on the tracker or the spaCy Gitter.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that tagger doesn't use multithreading, but my question is more about what can be done to support multithreading in custom defined pipeline functions. In my score_vocab_pipe function I run similarity function for every token in the document against a set of predefined lexemes so the benefit in multithreading the task would be significant.

Comment: If you implement your function in Cython and can release the GIL around around the main part of the work, you'll be able to use a `prange()` loop. The blog post explains how I did this.

Once you've got the function multi-threaded, just accumulate a minibatch and work on it.